# while loop unary increment and decrement doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a while loop to decrements a counter before evaluating it in the condition statement.

for example this code would result in 6

```js
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while (counter)
    factorial *= counter--;

console.log(factorial);
```

while this result in 0

```js
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while (counter--)
    factorial *= counter;

console.log(factorial);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why is it that the while(counter--) doesn't enter the loop - counter-- would result in a number after evaluation meaning that it should work, trying to find an explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while (counter--)
    factorial *= counter;

console.log(factorial);
```

The while condition is evaluated BEFORE changing the counter.
So on the first loop you evaluate for 3 and pass on the vaue 2 for the multiplication.
Then you evaluate 2 > 0 and you pass 1 to the multiplication, since counter-- means that first the current value will be used and immediatly after the value will be reduced by 1.

So in the next step you evaluate if(1) which is true but you pass on 0, so the result of the multiplication is 0.
Then the while loop will fail the evaluation as the counter will be a falsy value, like 0

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that when you decrement in the condition, then in the body of the loop the value has already decremented.

Predecrement in order to break the loop when `counter` reaches `0`, and initialize `factorial` to `counter`.

```js
var counter = 3; // Infinite loop if `counter <= 0`
var factorial = counter;
while (--counter)
  factorial *= counter;
console.log(factorial);
```

Or use a `do...while` loop if you still want to initialize it to `1`

```js
var counter = 3; // Infinite loop if `counter < 0`
var factorial = 1;
do factorial *= counter;
while (--counter);
console.log(factorial);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't decrement like that. You're basically writing.

```
while (counter)
    factorial *= counter -= 1;
```

Which is simply wrong. You want

```
while (counter > 0) {
    factorial *= counter;
    counter--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial sample code and question of decrementing a variable `counter` before it is being evaluated in a for loop, I came up with this solution:

```
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while (--counter)
    factorial *= counter;

console.log(factorial);
```

As you can see, the counter gets decremented, before it is being evaluated.

The feedback however was, that it now gives the "wrong result".

So in this updated post, I want to present the way I'd write a recursive factorial function. Calculated factorials are stored in the `f` variable, so that intermediary values don't have to be computed over and over again.

```
let f = [];

const factorial = n => {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    return 1;
  if (f[n] > 0)
    return f[n];
  f[n] = factorial(n-1) * n;
  return f[n];
}

console.log(factorial(3));
```

Comment: The counter gets decremented before the evaluation. Isn't this what was asked?

Comment: But the factorial of 3 is 6, not 2.

Comment: That is correct, but the variable is simply called `counter`. I simply helped in answering `I'm trying to get a while loop to decrements a counter before evaluating it in the condition statement.`, not how to write a function on calculating the factorial.

Comment: in any case, I updated my answer to how I would write a factorial function, but it really has nothing to do with --counter any longer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the prefix version of the decrement operator, e.g.

`while (--counter)`

> If used prefix (for example, --x), then it returns the value after decrementing.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 0):

Here if you want to output as required then use the code below

```
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while ( x = counter--)
    factorial *= x

console.log(factorial);

Output : 6

**Explanation :** 
 let x = 3;
 var p = x--; // here, p = 3 and x = 2
so, in your parameter you passed 2 instead of 3 that's why giving a wrong ans .
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically difference between post- and pre-decrementation and place of its evaluation.

When you write `x--` it returns current value of x, then decrements it. Opposite to that, pre-incrementation/decrementation returns incremented/decremented value immediately.

When `while` condition is evaluated, the counter is decremented there so in the loop's body you get already modified counter value. That differs from `factorial *= counter--;` where counter is decremented after counting the factorial (because of post decrementation).

In order to see how it works in practice see examples below:

```js
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while (counter) {
    console.log("Counter value before:" + counter);
    factorial *= counter--;
    console.log("Counter value after:" + counter);
}

console.log(factorial);
```

```js
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

while (counter--) {
    console.log("Counter value:" + counter);
    factorial *= counter;
}

console.log(factorial);
```

In order the same behavior as in original example you can rewrite `while` loop to `do { } while` using predecrementation (`--counter`):

```js
var counter = 3;
var factorial = 1;

do {
    console.log("Counter value:" + counter);
    factorial *= counter;
} while(--counter);

console.log(factorial);
```